# What should everyone know about PDEs?

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Suppose I'm going into a field where it's unlikely that I will ever see a PDE.
Assuming I have a graduate level background in analysis, what should I know about PDEs to have a general understanding of the topic? The book by Evans, for example, seems more comprehensive than necessary. I'd like to reduce it to a list of around say, five, chapters or topics I should know well.

Comment: I don't use PDE's much at all but I do find it useful every once in a while to have a good understanding of the heat equation and the wave equation.

Comment: Take a look at Arnold's PDE notes. Very concise, and physically motivated, while conveying essential ideas about the most common PDEs.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my attempt:

- Harmonic functions
- The Dirichlet problem on bounded domains

  - Perron's method
  - $H^1$ method: Existence, regularity (Weyl's lemma)
- Poisson equations: Regularity in $H^k$ scale, Schauder estimates
- Spectral properties of the Laplacian on bounded domains

  - Hilbert-Schmidt theory, variational characterization of the eigenvalues
  - Eigenvalue comparison theorems, Weyl's asymptotic law
  - Courant's nodal domain theorem, Pleijel's theorem
- The heat equation: Heat kernel, Tychonov's uniqueness theorem, maximum principles, backward uniqueness
- The wave equation: Explicit formulas, finite speed of propagation, Huygens principle
- First order equations: Method of characteristics, Hamilton-Jacobi equations, conservation laws